# In Gnome Shell, how do I prevent all windows of an app from getting focus when I focus just one of them?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

For example, I have two monitors, each with `gnome-terminal` maximized. When I select one of the instances of `gnome-terminal` I don't want the one on the other monitor to get focus as well (because I often have something I want to look at at the same time on the other monitor).

Note that it's only when I select the window using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>. If I click on a window with the mouse or select the sub-window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> it does what I expect (i.e. doesn't focus the other windows).

I don't really want to switch away from the default alt-tab switcher. Is there a way to do this with the default alt-tab switcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's no way to do it. One workaround, however, is to use the "window switcher" instead. Set:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications '["<Super>Tab"]'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows '["<Alt>Tab"]'
```

With that, <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> will execute the default application switcher where application windows are grouped together, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> will execute a more classical switcher where every window of all applications is shown separately.

Comment: To make those shortcuts work in backward direction too:
```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward '["<Shift><Super>Tab"]'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward '["<Shift><Alt>Tab"]'
```